# Rails API: How do you standardize your JSON responses?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now, upon a successful call to my Rails API Backend, I might do one of the following...

```
render json: {user_id: @user.id, token: token}
```

or

```
render json: {status: :success}
```

And upon an unsuccessful result, I may do something like

```
render json: {status: :failure, error: "The email or password entered is not correct."}
```

My question is... what's the best way to standardize this.

If my iOS app goes searching for a json dictionary value of dict[@"error"] it's not always going to find it. Should every single render message I have regardless of success... have a 'status' key, or an 'error' key or both.

Or is it better for the front end to deal with this, and if dict[@"error"]/dict[@"status"] happen to not exist... then it knows the back end did not have an error occur otherwise it would have said so?

Answer (score 2):

The way you are rendering the responses is fine. On your client side, it's should be all about handling properly HTTP status codes.

`render status: :ok` -> should return a HTTP status code 200, which means a successful request. Then your client (iphone app) does know that with a successfull request you get the user id and token.

`render status: :bad_request` -> should return a HTTP status code 400, which means unsuccessfull request, then your client would know that an error occured, and based on your standards he can look up the error field of the json response

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar question in terms of how do we standardize the JSON response.

By default Rails generates this sort of JSON from a post model,

posts: [
{
  id: 22198,
  title: "Using GitHub Pages To Host Your Website",
  date: "2013-08-16 09:30:20",
},
{
  id: 22196,
  title: "Running Tests in Ruby on Rails – Treehouse Quick Tip",
  date: "2013-08-15 14:30:48",
}
]

But is there any standard to power the Rails API for an iPhone APP?

What are the standards or typical success/failure response format an iOS developer would expect to see?